# How to create ClusterPodMonitoring in GCP?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, prometheus

I'm trying to follow their docs and create this pod monitoring
i apply it and i see nothing in metrics

what am i doing wrong?

```
apiVersion: monitoring.googleapis.com/v1
kind: ClusterPodMonitoring
metadata:
  name: monitoring
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: blah
  namespaceSelector:
    any: true
  endpoints:
  - port: metrics
    interval: 30s
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the offical [documnentation](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/managed-prometheus/setup-managed):

The following manifest defines a PodMonitoring resource, prom-example, in the NAMESPACE_NAME namespace. The resource uses a Kubernetes label selector to find all pods in the namespace that have the label app with the value prom-example. The matching pods are scraped on a port named metrics, every 30 seconds, on the /metrics HTTP path.

```
apiVersion: monitoring.googleapis.com/v1
kind: PodMonitoring
metadata:
  name: prom-example
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: prom-example
  endpoints:
  - port: metrics
    interval: 30s
```

To apply this resource, run the following command:

```
kubectl -n NAMESPACE_NAME apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/prometheus-engine/v0.5.0/examples/pod-monitoring.yaml
```

Also check the document on [Obeserving your GKE clusters](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/gke/observing).

**UPDATE:**

After applying the manifests, the managed collection will be running but no metrics will be generated. You must deploy a PodMonitoring resource that scrapes a valid metrics endpoint to see any data in the Query UI.

Check the logs by running the below commands:

```
kubectl logs -f -ngmp-system -lapp.kubernetes.io/part-of=gmp

kubectl logs -f -ngmp-system -lapp.kubernetes.io/name=collector -c prometheus
```

If you see any error follow this [link](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/managed-prometheus/troubleshooting#ingest-problems) to troubleshoot.

Comment: I did this and query up in the promql and nothing...